# How to find change percent from previous year

Tags: sql, postgresql

Purchases table

```
create table purchase ( 
id integer primary key, 
purchasedate date not null, 
purchasesum numeric(12,2) not null )
```

contains  purchase sums. How to find change percent from previos year:

```
select
  extract( year from purchasedate ),
  sum( purchasesum),
  ( sum( purchasesum) - previous row sum( previous purchasesum ) ) /
                previous row sum( previous purchasesum ) * 100
from purchase
group by 1
order by 1
```

Result should be

```
2014     1200
2015     1320    +10%
2016     14784   +12%
2017     1774.08 +20%
2018     1596.67 -10% 
2019     2075.67 +30%
```

Using Postgresql 9.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMB's solution is fine.  A somewhat shorter way to express it is:

```
select extract(year from purchasedate),
       sum(purchasesum),
       (sum(purchasesum) * 100 /
        lag(sum(purchasesum)) over (order by min(purchasedate)
       ) - 100 
from purchase
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Note that both solutions assume that there are no gaps in the years.

If this is a possibility, then a `range` window frame solves the problem:

```
select extract(year from purchasedate),
       sum(purchasesum),
       (sum(purchasesum) * 100 /
        sum(sum(purchasesum)) over (order by extract(year from purchasedate)
                                    range between interval 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
       ) - 100 
from purchase
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    extract(year from purchasedate),
    sum(purchasesum),
    (
        sum(purchasesum) 
        - lag(sum(purchasesum)) over(order by extract(year from purchasedate))
    ) 
        / lag(sum(purchasesum)) over(order by extract(year from purchasedate)) 
        * 100 percent_increase
from purchase
group by 1
order by 1
```